# First or Default Node in Tree view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to set a **node** with particular text as **first node** in **tree view**..  I need the code something like

```
subOrdinatesTreeView.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == emp.LPN);
```

How to do it?
Can any one help me...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I got partial answer.. This is the code to get a **node with particular value**
 


 TreeNode tnKey = 
   subOrdinatesTreeView.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(r => r.Text == emp.LPN).ToArray()[0];

Comment: You should [edit] your question to indicate the progress you made.

Answer (score 1):

I got partial answer.. This is the code to get a node with particular value

```
 TreeNode tnKey =  subOrdinatesTreeView.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(r => r.Text == emp.LPN).ToArray()[0];
```